# Value assigned to variable does not match datatip (hover) or watch expression for unicode string comparision

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am doing a between two variables, one has `"＜def"` as its value and the other has `"<def"` as its value.

```
Dim str1 = "＜test"
Dim str2 = "<test"

Dim different = str1<>str2
```

When the program runs, the variable different is set to false.  If I stop on that line and put the mouse over the comparison, the datatip shows `str<>str2|True', if I put the expression in the watch window the value is True.  But after the statement is executed, the variable different will be False?

What is going on here?  A bug in the compiler or a bug in visual studio?

Comment: I just ran your code in a Console app and `different` was `True` after executing that third line.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: you're right, it does.  But I assure that it doesn't in my other application. Exact same code, different results.

Comment: Then there's something wrong with that other project.  Something may be corrupt.

Comment: Where is the breakpoint when you see that `different` is set to `false`?  Is execution stopped on that line?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway:I have an if condition on the next line that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET inherited a couple of file/project settings from VB6, one of these is the issue: Option Compare Text/Binary.

In order to remain consistent with VB6 and the VB.Net design philosophy, VB.Net treats string comparison differently than it does other reference types.  Specifically, comparing strings isn't just a simple reference check, instead it done using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Operators.CompareString. The main purpose of this is to give an intuitive and consistent experience.  This method takes 3 parameters, 2 strings and a boolean.  The value of the boolean is determined by the value of Option Compare setting. If it is true (Option Compare Text), a case and unicode INsensitive comparison is done.

In short, with Option Compare Text `"s"="S"` and `"＜def" = "<def"`, and in my project it was set to Text.

A dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rknrLo